# JS timeout function call css transitions

Tags: javascript, css, slideshow, css-transitions, settimeout

Creating a slideshow with JS and using CSS opacity transitions for the transition of photo to photo.

I have the body set up like this

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <img src="one.jpg" id="image" class="fadeIn" />
    <img src="two.jpg" id="bImage" class="fadeOut" />
</div>
```

When this snippet of code is run on a timer

```
    pImg.className = "fadeOut";
    bImg.className = "fadeIn";
    num = three;
    dImg = "p";
    t2 = setTimeout(setImage(num,dImg),20000);
    clearTimeout(t2);
```

It is suppose to transition the opacity and show the new photo, which It does fine. The problem is after the transition happens it changes the URL (that's what the num = three; is for it points to a var string link and setImage does what it says) too quick so you end up seeing a short glimpse of the third image before it transfers to the second image.

That's why I created the setTimeout call and clear. I clear it because after it runs that code it iterates through if else that runs similar code.

The problem with my code is that no matter what I set the timeout to it doesn't make a difference on how quick the image is set. It calls the function because the photos in the body does change but the timeout doesn't make any difference.

This is probably a wonky attempt at a slideshow with transitions but I don't get why the timeout doesnt make a difference. Maybe I'm using the timeout function wrong. 
Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I did not understand everything, but you seem to call `clearTimeout` right after `setTimeout`, so it just cancels the timer

Comment: Please post all your code. On second thought: take a look at [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)